# Get whole and fractional part of a double

Tags: matlab, math

I have this:
 0.8765 number
and i would like to retrieve the whole part of the double as well as the fractional part without the 0. in front of it. Does anyone know how i can do this? 
I've been able to use `fix(A)`to get the whole part. The only thing missing is the fractional part.

Comment: `0.8765 - 0` doesnt quite cut it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So why not just subtracting?

```
A = 1.8345
BeforeComma = num2str(fix(A))
AfterComma = strrep(num2str(A - BeforeComma),['0.'],'')
```

A little more elegant would be to use `regexp`

```
A = 1.8345
splittedNumber = regexp(num2str(A),'\.','split')
[BeforeComma, AfterComma] = splittedNumber{:}
```

---

```
A =

    1.8345


BeforeComma =

1


AfterComma =

8345
```

---

If you want doubles with a predefined number of digits, you can do:

```
A = 1.834512
digits = 4
B = round(A,digits)
splittedNumber = str2double(regexp(num2str(A),'\.','split'));
[BeforeComma, AfterComma]  = deal(splittedNumber(1), splittedNumber(2))
```

Comment: `0.8765 - 0` doesnt quite cut it

Comment: @TonyOkoth So you want to get strings afterwards?

Comment: yes, but without the `0. ` infront of it. So not only get it, but also make it whole.

Comment: @TonyOkoth have a look at my edit. Are strings alright? if you want doubles again, you need do specify how many digits after comma you want to be part of the double. Because `1.8345` is set up by me, if it is the result of a calculation it could be much longer, but still not everything is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

--Get the wholepart with Fix
WholePart = fix(A)

--Get the fractional part
FractionalPart = A-WholePart

--Convert fractionalpart to string
strFractionalPart = num2str(FractionalPart)

--Substring strFractionalPart for all characters after 2nd character "0."
substring(strFractionalPart, 3, length(strFractionalPart)-2)